# document save function not working in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, meanjs

I am updating the document "Order.attempt_status" from "open" to "closed" using the following code

```
AttemptSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  var attempt = this;
  Order.findById(this.order).exec(function(err, order){
    if(err) next(err);
    if(!order) next(new Error('could not load order with order_id:' + this.order));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(order));
    order._doc.attempt_status = attempt.attempt_status;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(order));
    order.save(function(err){
      if(err) next(err);
      else next();
    });
  });
});
```

when I debug it see that attempt_status gets changed but updated document is not saved in database. Following is the debug screen.

[image]

click on https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByCPT.png if image is visible. console print is

```
{
  "_id": "54a26634a4800130eb95be19",
  "attempt_status": "open",
  ....
  ....
}

{
  "_id": "54a26634a4800130eb95be19",
  "attempt_status": "closed",
  ....
  ....
}
```

Comment: could you paste the debug log as strings.cant view the image

Comment: what is the best way to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't modify the private `_doc` object directly, assign the model instance's top-level properties so that Mongoose can track the changes and apply them when you call `save`.

```
order.attempt_status = attempt.attempt_status;
```